# Resolve shortened url in Android

Tags: java, android, url-shortener

How do I resolve a shortened url (bit.ly/dfasdfasf) to the re-directed url in android?

Answer (score 4):

You have to request the URL and then inspect the response to determine where the server is redirecting you to.  You can do this by using [Android's HTTP libraries](http://masl.cis.gvsu.edu/2010/04/05/android-code-sample-asynchronous-http-connections/) or [Java Sockets](http://www.anddev.org/tcp_sockets-t276.html).  Alternatively, if you know it's a bit.ly URL, you can use [their API](http://code.google.com/p/bitly-api/wiki/ApiDocumentation#/v3/expand) to expand the shortened url.

Answer (score 2):

You would probably want to use the Bit.ly API [`expand`](http://code.google.com/p/bitly-api/wiki/ApiDocumentation#/v3/expand) function.

From the docs:

> Given a bitly URL or hash (or
>   multiple), /v3/expand decodes it and
>   returns back the target URL

Answer (score 1):

The HttpURLConnection class redirect the connection in a max of 5 jumps.